# Signing a Package in MAC

Tags: macos, certificate, packagemaker

I have a C++ code which I build on Netbeans (8.0.1) on MAC OSX 10.10.

Now I want to package this binary so I'm using PackageMaker. Once the build on PackageMaker finishes it asks to sign it, I clicked 'Allow'.

Then I open terminal and checked if the package was signed successfully, and I got:

```
codesign -v G16.pkg
G16.pkg: code object is not signed at all.
```

I login the apple developer "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" page and I have:

- 2 Developer ID Application certificate
- 4 Developer ID Installer
- 1 Mac App Distribution
- 1 Mac Development
- 1 Mac Installer Distribution

In the KeyChain I have 1 certificate under "My certificate" and 6 under "Certificate".

So my questions are:

1. What are the differences between all the certificate?
2. Which certificate do I need to use?
3. What do I do wrong?

Please help me!!! thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

`codesign` is for signing of applications (not installers).
You should use `productsign` to sign pkg files. The certificate you should be using is "`Developer ID Installer`". (Full name of your certificate as shown in your keychain)

```
productsign --sign 'Developer ID Installer: Vikrams' 'pkg_path/temp.pkg' 'pkg_path/signed_temp.pkg'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! somehow finally it works from the PackageMaker itself.